# SVG -> TCPDF gradient mismatch

Tags: pdf, svg, gradient, tcpdf

I have the following SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800" height="150" viewBox="0 0 800 150" xml:space="preserve">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-400" y1="-150" x2="-400" y2="0">
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,64,64);stop-opacity: 1"/>
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(230,57,155);stop-opacity: 1"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect x="-400" y="-75" rx="0" ry="0" width="800" height="150" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: url(#SVGID_0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(400.5 75.5)"/>
</svg>
```

I am converting this to PDF using TCPDF:

```
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/testsvg.svg', $x=0, $y=0, $w='', $h='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);
```

As you can see from the image below, the gradient is applied wrongly.

[image]

Based on the illustrator image, it seems like TCPDF applies the center of the gradient to the bottom edge. If I manually move the center to the top edge then it looks very close to the original.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have a different result if you remove the transform?

Comment: Hi Danny, no afraid not. Same result.

Comment: And if you remove gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"? (which then defaults to gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox")

Comment: Hi Danny. Same result I am afraid.

Comment: Raise an issue on [its bugtracker](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf) and/or download the source code and fix it.

Comment: Problem is they have moved on to a new project whereby they aren't updating this anymore. And I am not really sure where in the source code the issue is.

Comment: Go to https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/tcpdf.php#L23077 to https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/tcpdf.php#L23179 Try logging the variables and compare them to original SVG gradient parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of how the rect is positioned. It actually starts outside the viewbox and then both the gradient and the box get transformed. For example the box and the gradient `x` parameter are both -400. This is overly complex and I think some of the parameters are getting cancelled out by the `$fitonpage=true` parameter or the translations are being applied differently:

`<rect x="-400" y="-75" rx="0" ry="0" width="800" height="150" style="... transform="translate(400.5 75.5)"/>`

Based on the supplied examples there isn't really any point to this trickery. The only purpose appears to be modifying the gradient start and end colors. I would just move the rect to start at 0,0, remove the transforms, and then modify the gradient colors and stops to achieve the same effect the correct way:

```
<linearGradient y2="150" x2="0" y1="0" x1="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="SVGID_0">
<stop
       style="stop-color:#f13c73;stop-opacity:1"
       id="stop4139"
       offset="0" />
<stop
       style="stop-color:#e6399b;stop-opacity:1"
       id="stop4141"
       offset="0.40" />
</linearGradient>
<rect
     id="rect4143"
     style="opacity:1;fill:url(#SVGID_0);fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none"
     height="150"
     width="800"
     ry="0"
     rx="0"
     y="0"
     x="0" />
```

The changes that matter are the removal of all the strange negative offsets on the rect and gradient and the change of the gradient stop colors and position to recreate the same gradient without the need to use cropping and transforms.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer SpliFF. Problem is I get the SVG from fabricJS which makes use of the negative transformation values etc., and modifying that library seems like a bigger task than trying to fix tcpdf.

Comment: The relevant SVG data is 2 XML nodes. Can you just apply the changes via an intermediate script? Or better yet adjust your fabricjs so you aren't creating elements outside the canvas?